# ReactJS - How to print all the content of a Scrollable elment with react-to-print

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-to-print

I have a `<div>` tag that has a list of elements, the list can be long so I gave a fixed height to the `<div>` tag and `overflow:auto` property to have a scrollable list in case of overflow.

Now I have a `button` at the bottom of this `<div>` to print the content of `<div>`. I am using `react-to-print` library as it seemed the easiest way to print the contents of my `<div>` along with the CSS.

The problem is that the print preview is showing only the elements present in the viewport, but I want all the elements in the `<div>` to print.

I can not use the `overflow: visible` property on my `<div>` as I definitely need the `<div>` to be a scrollable element also I can not place the `button` to print the list inside my `<div>` as users cant keep scrolling to the end of list to print it.

Here is a sandbox to play around: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-wifyd?file=/demo.js:337-341

link to react-to-print: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print

Any help is highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `@print` media queries to your div and increase the height of the div while printing alone?

I noticed it was not printing the viewport, rather it was printing only the
top list of the div.

i.e The part of div that is visible only comes while printing.

Something like

```css
@media print {
  div{
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add css rule with "!important" will solve the problem.

```
@media print {
  #scrollableDiv {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100% !important;
    overflow: visible;
  }
}
```